# Next button is disabled in second step installing the "delete user data" extension in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

Even though the second step's (Review APIs enabled and resources created) Next button is disabled, I can click on the third step, and its Next button is enabled. But when I click it or the fourth step (Configure Extension), nothing happens. No configuration options are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to happen when Storage is not enabled in your Firebase project. So go to the Storage tab in the Firebase console, and complete the initialization there - even if you don't (want to) use Cloud Storage in your Firebase project.

This provisioning of Storage used to happen automatically when you'd create a new project, but is now only done on demand.